# File not found Flutter/Flutter.h

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-dependencies, crashlytics

I am continuously getting Flutter/Flutter.h file not found issue after adding firebase_crashlytics to the project.
Flutter Sdk: 2.2.2
firebase_crashlytics: ^2.0.6
I tried lots of solutions form stackoverflow already but still unable to run for ios.

Answer (score 2):

The only solution worked for me is given down.
Changing these lines in my podfile did the trick

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'YES'
      config.build_settings['IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET'] = '10.0'
    end
  end
end
```

to

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    flutter_additional_ios_build_settings(target)
  end
end
```

And also I strictly followed firebase_crashlytics [configuration](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started) for native