# fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found in pipeline

Tags: ios, flutter, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up a build pipeline on Azure DevOps for my flutter project. The android build works but the iOS build is giving "fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found".

This is my pipeline:

```yaml
trigger:
  - develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.15'

steps:
  - task: FlutterInstall@0
    displayName: Install Flutter $(FLUTTER_VERSION)
    inputs:
      channel: 'stable'
      version: 'custom'
      customVersion: $(FLUTTER_VERSION)
  - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    displayName: Install Apple Certificate
    inputs:
      certSecureFile: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_FILE)
      certPwd: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD)'
      keychain: 'temp'
  - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    displayName: Install Apple Provisioning Profile
    inputs:
      provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
      provProfileSecureFile: $(APPLE_PROVISIONINGPROFILE_FILE)
  - bash: |
      set -e ; set -o pipefail
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter clean
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter pub get
      
      ##################################
      cd ios
      pod install
      xcodebuild -workspace Runner.xcworkspace -scheme dev -destination 'generic/platform=iOS'
      cd ..
      ##################################

      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter build ios --flavor dev -t lib/main.dart --no-sound-null-safety # build breaks here
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter build apk --flavor dev -t lib/main.dart --no-sound-null-safety
```

Here `FLUTTER_VERSION` is `2.0.5`, and the certificate and provisioning files come from the Azure Pipelines Library. They are all found and the installation steps are working correctly.

Everything works until `flutter build ios`, which gives said error. I had the same issue a while ago on my MacBook Pro and I fixed it by opening the `ios` project with XCode and running Product => Build, the lines enclosed in hashes were added to mimic that behaviour but I'm not 100% sure they are correct.

What I tried:

- I tried adding the lines enclosed with hashes in an attempt to mimic the "Product => Build" XCode feature, which solved this issue on my MacBook Pro a while ago. This isn't working though, the build is fine but then the `flutter build` command fails with the same error.
- I tried [the solution proposed in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67002844/fatal-error-flutter-flutter-h-file-not-found-in-flutter), however it's not applicable in my scenario because these files are not pushed to the repository thus they don't actually exist
- I tried [the solution proposed in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67998790/file-not-found-flutter-flutter-h) but again, this file doesn't exist on the repository.

The weird thing here is that on the MacBook Pro I had this issue once and I resolved it with the "Product => Build" feature. I can easily build the iOS package on my MacBook so I'm thinking there might be some configuration in my MacBook that flutter/xcode aren't finding in the isolated pipeline environment.

The relevant part of the log:

```
CompileC /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.o /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/2.0.5-stable/macos/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'firebase_crashlytics' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods
    export LANG\=en_US.US-ASCII
    /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -x objective-c -target armv7-apple-ios10.0 -fmessage-length\=0 -fdiagnostics-show-note-include-stack -fmacro-backtrace-limit\=0 -std\=gnu11 -fobjc-arc -fmodules -gmodules -fmodules-cache-path\=/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex -fmodules-prune-interval\=86400 -fmodules-prune-after\=345600 -fbuild-session-file\=/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache.noindex/Session.modulevalidation -fmodules-validate-once-per-build-session -Wnon-modular-include-in-framework-module -Werror\=non-modular-include-in-framework-module -fmodule-name\=firebase_crashlytics -Wno-trigraphs -fpascal-strings -O0 -fno-common -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-missing-prototypes -Werror\=return-type -Wdocumentation -Wunreachable-code -Wno-implicit-atomic-properties -Werror\=deprecated-objc-isa-usage -Wno-objc-interface-ivars -Werror\=objc-root-class -Wno-arc-repeated-use-of-weak -Wimplicit-retain-self -Wduplicate-method-match -Wno-missing-braces -Wparentheses -Wswitch -Wunused-function -Wno-unused-label -Wno-unused-parameter -Wunused-variable -Wunused-value -Wempty-body -Wuninitialized -Wconditional-uninitialized -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wno-shadow -Wno-four-char-constants -Wno-conversion -Wconstant-conversion -Wint-conversion -Wbool-conversion -Wenum-conversion -Wno-float-conversion -Wnon-literal-null-conversion -Wobjc-literal-conversion -Wshorten-64-to-32 -Wpointer-sign -Wno-newline-eof -Wno-selector -Wno-strict-selector-match -Wundeclared-selector -Wdeprecated-implementations -DPOD_CONFIGURATION_DEBUG_DEV\=1 -DDEBUG\=1 -DCOCOAPODS\=1 -DLIBRARY_VERSION\=@\"0.4.0-1\" -DLIBRARY_NAME\=@\"flutter-fire-cls\" -DPERMISSION_EVENTS\=0 -DPERMISSION_REMINDERS\=0 -DPERMISSION_CONTACTS\=0 -DPERMISSION_MICROPHONE\=0 -DPERMISSION_SPEECH_RECOGNIZER\=0 -DPERMISSION_PHOTOS\=0 -DPERMISSION_LOCATION\=0 -DPERMISSION_NOTIFICATIONS\=0 -DPERMISSION_MEDIA_LIBRARY\=0 -DPERMISSION_SENSORS\=0 -DOBJC_OLD_DISPATCH_PROTOTYPES\=0 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode_12.4.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS14.4.sdk -fstrict-aliasing -Wprotocol -Wdeprecated-declarations -g -Wno-sign-conversion -Winfinite-recursion -Wcomma -Wblock-capture-autoreleasing -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-semicolon-before-method-body -Wunguarded-availability -fembed-bitcode-marker -index-store-path /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Index/DataStore -iquote /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/firebase_crashlytics-generated-files.hmap -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/firebase_crashlytics-own-target-headers.hmap -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/firebase_crashlytics-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap -ivfsoverlay /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/all-product-headers.yaml -iquote /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/firebase_crashlytics-project-headers.hmap -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics/include -I/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Headers/Public -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/DerivedSources-normal/armv7 -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/DerivedSources/armv7 -I/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/DerivedSources -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/FirebaseCrashlytics -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/FirebaseDynamicLinks -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/FirebaseInstallations -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/FirebaseInstanceID -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/FirebaseMessaging -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/GoogleDataTransport -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/GoogleUtilities -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/PromisesObjC -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_core -F/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Products/Debug-dev-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/GoogleAppMeasurement/Frameworks -include /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Target\ Support\ Files/firebase_crashlytics/firebase_crashlytics-prefix.pch -MMD -MT dependencies -MF /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.d --serialize-diagnostics /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.dia -c /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/2.0.5-stable/macos/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m -o /Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-gsjhxdjmxuzkkbgjdidjocbaqrkc/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-dev-iphoneos/firebase_crashlytics.build/Objects-normal/armv7/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.o
In file included from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/2.0.5-stable/macos/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.m:5:
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/2.0.5-stable/macos/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.h:8:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
While building module 'firebase_core' imported from /Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/2.0.5-stable/macos/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_crashlytics-0.4.0+1/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCrashlyticsPlugin.h:12:
In file included from <module-includes>:1:
In file included from /Users/runner/work/1/s/ios/Pods/Target Support Files/firebase_core/firebase_core-umbrella.h:13:
/Users/runner/hostedtoolcache/Flutter/2.0.5-stable/macos/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_core-0.7.0/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseCorePlugin.h:8:9: fatal error: 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found
#import <Flutter/Flutter.h>
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
2 errors generated.
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After several hours of trial and error I finally solved the issue. Turned out I had to do two things:

- Run `flutter version` at the beginning of the pipeline.
- Put Flutter's `bin` directory in the system `PATH` before building for iOS.

I honestly don't know what magic is happening behind but I suspect that `flutter version` internally checks if all the libararies and binaries are correctly downloaded and fixes this silently, while updating the `PATH` variable gives flutter/xcodebuild the right path to find the required files. I'm not sure about this though.

This is the updated pipeline:

```yaml
trigger:
  - develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS-10.15'

steps:
  - task: FlutterInstall@0
    displayName: Install Flutter $(FLUTTER_VERSION)
    inputs:
      channel: 'stable'
      version: 'custom'
      customVersion: $(FLUTTER_VERSION)
  - task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
    displayName: Install Apple Certificate
    inputs:
      certSecureFile: $(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_FILE)
      certPwd: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_PASSWORD)'
      keychain: 'temp'
  - task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
    displayName: Install Apple Provisioning Profile
    inputs:
      provisioningProfileLocation: 'secureFiles'
      provProfileSecureFile: $(APPLE_PROVISIONINGPROFILE_FILE)
  - bash: |
      set -e ; set -o pipefail
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter --version
      export PATH=$PATH:$(FlutterToolPath)
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter clean
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter pub get
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter build ios --flavor dev -t lib/main.dart --no-sound-null-safety
      $(FlutterToolPath)/flutter build apk --flavor dev -t lib/main.dart --no-sound-null-safety
```