# Xcode 13 'Flutter/Flutter.h' file not found when I add Facebook App Event

Tags: swift, xcode, flutter, facebook

When i add Facebook App Events (v 12.3.2) to flutter project i have error in Xcode.

This not help [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67998790/file-not-found-flutter-flutter-h[enter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67998790/file-not-found-flutter-flutter-h%5Benter) image description here][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKUWo.png)

Problem in Xcode
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKUWo.png)
Problem in Android studio when I use flutter run -d
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MA9ip.png)

Flutter doctor and flutter doctor -v don't show any issue

Answer (score 0):

try this steps:

1. Backup Runner folder
2. Delete the ios folder
3. Go to a terminal and execute `flutter create .` in the flutter project folder
4. Paste your Runner folder back into the ios folder
5. `pod deintegrate` in the ios folder
6. `pod install` also in the ios folder
7. `flutter clean` in the flutter project folder
8. `flutter pub get`
9. `flutter run`

Please note that if you use firebase you need to re-insert the GoogleService-Info.plist file

Comment: Now i have problem 'No such module 'Flutter' and probably when i add package from facebook i back to flutter.h file not found

Comment: then i don't know